# IoT Hub to Azure Function - The listener for function was unable to start Azure.Messaging.EventHubs could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Following guides to link [an Azure Function to IoT Hub message receipt](http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Processing-data-from-IoT-Hub-in-Azure-Functions), I get the error:

```
[2022-07-28T23:11:20.651Z] The listener for function 'DataFromDevice' was unable to start.
System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (The messaging entity
'sb://iothub-ns-mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/messages/events' could not be found. 
To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.  (messages/events)).
```

I pulled the connection string from the `IoT Hub -> Built-in endpoints -> Event Hub compatible endpoint` per the guides, I had to drop the `EntityPath` at the end however.

My code otherwise compiles and uploads OK (with runtime error mentioned above), and code is below:

```
using IoTHubTrigger = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubTriggerAttribute;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class DataFromDevice
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    
    [FunctionName("DataFromDevice")]
    public void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "IoTHubConnectionString")]EventData message, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Span)}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages/events` is the internal name IoT Hub uses to route messages. However, if you want to read from that stream, you must use a different name.

You can find the correct Event Hub name in the same place you got the endpoint from:
[image: Screenshot of the Azure Portal, showing the event hub name]

You can use that name instead of

```cs
IoTHubTrigger("messages/events"
```